# Remove breakpoints in chrome dev tools script panel

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging i added a breakpoint in chrome script console. But after debugging i had removed it.

Even after removing it, it still persists and everytime i loads the page the script gets paused.
I had manually removed that breakpoint, tried clearing cookies and cache, even restarted the browser, but it still persists.

Please tell me how to remove it
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you detach DevTools, then press Ctrl+Shift+I to open DevTools on DevTools and tell us if there are any exceptions in the Conole after you tried to remove the breakpoint?

FYI, you can report DevTools bugs at http://webkit.org/new-inspector-bug

Comment: The up-to-date URL to report new bugs is http://crbug.com/new, choose the "Developer Tools" component if asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens to me I've noticed, which may be a bug or may be due to the page being reloaded before you play all the way through the load you're currently broken on.

If you let the code finish, and then unselect the break points that may help fix it.